# What is a specific smart card transmission protocol?

Tags: smartcard, smartcard-reader

How I can understand a specific card use which protocol to communicate with a smart card reader? and also which frequency and which baud rate?
I mean T=0 or T=1? synchronous or asynchronous?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While memory cards like SLE4428 etc are synchronous (and have protocol like 2-wire, 3-wire, i-square-c), all processor cards are asynchronous. T=0 is a character-based and T=1 a block-based protocol. The card and the reader have their own set of restrictions concerning baud rates; the card indicates its capabilities in the ATR, and the reader tries one of these in a process called PPS (protocol and parameter selection). If no PPS takes place a standard diving factor of 372 is applied to the external clock of 3.57 or 4.91 MHz. I suggest, that you take a look at ISO 7816-3 explaining stuff like this  and/or Rankl/Effing: The Smart Card Handbook for a start.